# using Scala to implement a life chat application

Tags: scala

I am very new to scala and am trying to learn what are the benefits of scala over other languages . for my practice I like to implement a small live chat.
I picked scala because of its Acor Model to handle concurrency part of the live chat app. 
But I like to learn that is there any disadvantage of using scala for developing a live chat ?
what is a better alternative ?
thanks

Comment: Note that what you are asking rather applies to Scala frameworks (Akka, Play, Lift, etc.) than to the Scala language itself.

Answer (score 4):

A chat service is almost the “hello, world” example of what is great about the actor model of concurrent processing! While Scala ships with [scala.actor](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.actors.package), they are somewhat deprecated and you should be looking at [Akka](http://www.akka.io/).

The blog post “[Getting started with Scala, Akka and Sbt: the chat example](http://charless.org/?p=105)” gives a pretty good worked example of a simple chat server and how to build and test it.

The followup comment you've had notes Play. Play is a web framework which is actually implemented in terms of Akka. Play is perhaps the next place you should look if you want to take your command-line chat server onto the web.

Answer (score 0):

[Lift](http://liftweb.net) also uses a chat application as it's hello world. If you'd like to go from Akka's command-line example to a web application example, check it out. You can follow [this tutorial](http://simply.liftweb.net/index-Chapter-2.html) to build it yourself.